# Override string conversion for custom classes in Nim

Tags: tostring, nim-lang

Is it possible to override whatever method is used when an object of a custom class is converted to a string for display?

For example, this code currently prints `(x: 4, y: 5)`, but I want it to print just `(4,5)`

```
type Point = object
    x: int
    y: int

let p = Point(x:4, y:5)
echo p
```

What proc/method/whatever do I implement to change the default Point->string conversion used by `echo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out; [`echo`'s docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#echo%2Cvarargs%5Btyped%2C%5D) says you just gotta overload the `$` operator:

```
from strformat import fmt

type Point = object
    x: int
    y: int

proc `$`(point: Point): string = fmt"({point.x}, {point.y})"


let p = Point(x:4, y:5)
echo p   # prints "(4, 5)"
```